# Why my code is behaving differently on local and not loading correct json response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I wanted to implement auto-populate city and state from zip code.

I found this link : [zipautocomplete](http://methvin.net/js/zip/)

This link is working super. Now I wanted to copy this code so right clicked and chosen view page source and there I found the html and ajax code.

I copied code created index.php on my localhost. I have also copied necessary files like jquery.min.js etc.

Now my code is same as that of link but I am not getting same output.

Here is code that I have copied :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ZIP code autocomplete test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">

body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

.ac_city { font-size: smaller; float: right; width: 70% }
.ac_zip { font-weight: bold; float: left; width: 25%; }

.ac_city, .ac_zip { margin: 0.1em 0; }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#zip, #city").autocomplete("zip_json.pl", {
        minChars: 2,
        selectFirst: true,
        matchSubset: true,
        width: 220,
        scrollHeight: 300,
        max: 1024,
        dataType: 'json',
        extraParams: {
            zip: function () {
                return $("#zip:focus").val();
            },
            city: function () {
                var c = $("#city:focus").val();
                return c && c + '%'
            }
        },
        parse: function (data) {
            var a = [];
            for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++)
                a.push({ data: data[i],
                         value: data[i].zip,
                         result: data[i].zip
                       });
            return a;
        },
        formatItem: function (item) {
            return "<span class='ac_zip'>" + item.zip + "</span>" +
                              "<span class='ac_city'>" + item.city +
                              ", " + item.state + "</span>";
        },
    });
    $("#zip, #city").result(function (event, item) {
        $("#zip").val(item.zip);
        $("#city").val(item.city);
        $("#state").val(item.state);
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Enter a zip code or city and it will start autocompleting with 2
  or more chars. Select an item from the list and it will fill in the
  zip, city and state.</p>
  <form>
    <label> ZIP: <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5"></label>
    <label> City: <input name="city" id="city" type="text" size="20"></label>
    <label> State: <input name="state" id="state" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2"></label>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I checked above code on local, actually the code working correctly but it is not picking correct 
json response. when I enter 2 numbers in zip field then it should show related zipcode which is showing on that website but on my local browswer it is loading all joson_zip.pl file's json data.

When I checked "NET" output from firebug tool, I found difference in json response of local output and link output.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the source there is

```
<script>
    $("#zip, #city").autocomplete("zip_json.pl", {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

`zip_json.pl` refers to something on the server: `http://methvin.net/js/zip/zip_json.pl`.
This is not a file, like you saved (JSON), but a [script](https://github.com/gmethvin/zipcity/blob/master/zip_json.pl). Check it out here: https://github.com/gmethvin/zipcity/blob/master/zip_json.pl

You should run it on you own pc, because you [will get an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource).

You should defenitely check out the sources on github, everything you need is in there
https://github.com/gmethvin/zipcity

Comment: NO its not like that. I have downloaded that .pl file on my local. Still it is not working.

Comment: @P1nGu1n because he have `zip_json.pl` file downloaded on local

Comment: @P1nGu1n:I tried your trick of using the URL : http://methvin.net/js/zip/zip_json.pl but it's not worked for me. I'm also facing the same issue as Akki. It's really a genuine issue.

Comment: Check my edited answer, `zip_json.pl` is a script, not a file

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
$("#zip, #city").autocomplete("zip_json.pl", {
```

to

```
$("#zip, #city").autocomplete("http://methvin.net/js/zip/zip_json.pl", {
```

that might not works either because of cross domain request
you best option is to have your server handeling the request